# Passing parameters to qgis:rastercalculator alg in custom Processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I am trying to use the qgis:rastercalculator algorithm inside a processing script and not able to find the correct syntax for specifying layer/band inputs. Below is a simple script to reproduce the problem. I am simply taking the input raster layer and returning it as output.

The same works fine with gdal:rastercalculator but fails with an unhelpful error:

> An error occurred while performing the calculation.

```
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination)
from qgis import processing


class RasterCalcProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
   
    def createInstance(self):
        return RasterCalcProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'rastercalctest'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'rastercalctest'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
                self.INPUT, 'INPUT', defaultValue=None
                
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(
                  self.OUTPUT, 'OUTPUT'
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        input = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
        output = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)
        params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '\"{}@1\"'.format(input),
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': [input],
            'OUTPUT':  parameters['OUTPUT'],
        }
        result = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', params, context=context)
        return {self.OUTPUT: result['OUTPUT']}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust your script so that it reads the `INPUT` parameter as a raster layer, instead of as a string. Accordingly, you'll need to call the `name()` method to access the layer name.

Inside `processAlgorithm()` method, replace:

```
input = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
```

by:

```
input = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
```

Additionally, replace:

```
'EXPRESSION': '\"{}@1\"'.format(input),
```

by:

```
'EXPRESSION': '\"{}@1\"'.format(input.name()),
```

---

Rationale:

When you read the (layer) parameter as a string, you get the layer id (e.g., `my_raster_0bf496de_d00c_48bb_bd9b_157a3d1b9164`), but what you need for your expression is the layer name (e.g., `my_raster`).